# More than one onEdit script for more than one tab

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

[link to sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qifos5xp3yops8qzRL-NwP65KT-PvpRo363RFRM9rbk/edit?usp=sharing)So yesterday I asked this question about how to make my script edit only one tab.  Not realizing I couldn't duplicate it to work for other tabs on the same sheet.

I have tabs titled 'WEB Graffiti' and 'Zone maintenance' that are identical and I can get the script to function on those tabs.
But, a third tab titled 'Maintenance' has more columns and I can't figure out how to direct the onEdit script to work on all three tabs.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var myRange = e.range;
  var theSheetName = myRange.getSheet().getName();

  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
    );
  }

  if(theSheetName == 'Zone submissions' || theSheetName == 'WEB Graffiti'){
  indirectTimestamp_(e);
  }
}

/**
* Inserts a timestamp in column T when column B is edited
* and column C contains the value TRUE.
*
* @param {testing} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function indirectTimestamp_(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 2
    || e.range.offset(0, 1).getDisplayValue() !== 'TRUE') {
    return;
  }
  const timestampCell = e.range.offset(0, 18);
  timestampCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('mmm" "d" "yyyy');
};
```

I want to add to this script a tab titled 'Maintenance' and function the same as above, except, I want it to put the timestamp on column AA. I need to put the below script somewhere to make it work.

```
  const timestampCell = e.range.offset(0, 25);
  timestampCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('mmm" "d" "yyyy');
```

Thanks

Comment: If you can share sample sheets with what you have worked on, that would be a great help.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qifos5xp3yops8qzRL-NwP65KT-PvpRo363RFRM9rbk/edit?usp=sharing